# JavaScript const and var and Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I have some code that is basically a class to encapsulate tracking with Google Analytics. It looks like

```
const cecTrack = window['cecTrack'] || ( () => {
    let _initialized;
    let _toTrack = [];
    let _gaUser;
    let _lastView;
    let _appName;
    let _campaignSource;
    let _gaKey;

    var _ga = function(){
        if(window['ga'] && arguments && arguments.length){
            const a = arguments;

            setTimeout(function(){
                window['ga'].apply(null, a);
            }, 500);
        }
    }

    var _gan = function(){
        if(window['ga'] && arguments && arguments.length){
            const a = arguments;

            window['ga'].apply(null, a);
        }
    }
```

. . . .

I have omitted the details specific to the application. I have seen the recommendation that let or const is preferred to var. Yet when I change either of these functions to something like

```
const _ga = () => {
```

Google Analytics doesn't seem to work. Something breaks the initialization. The only thing common to these functions is reference to a global variable. Could that be the problem? Anyone with direct experience with GA, do you have any advice that I might use so that I can replace var with const or?

Comment: Prefer `const` (and `let`) in *source* code - it's common to have production code with `var` so that the few strange people still using horribly outdated IE11 can still use your website. That aside, I don't see why `const _ga` would be causing problems here, unless you're reassigning it somewhere

Comment: It would make a difference if it were declared in a global scope. Variables declared with `var` become properties of the `window` object. But, this is inside a function. So, that's not relevant here. Mentioning it since you are accessing a lot of `window[...]`.

Answer (score 1):

`arguments` is only available in `function` keyword not in arrow functions.

Way 1. `const _ga = (...arguments) => {`

Way 2. `const _ga = function () {`